# Fatal Exception: AsyncTask #1 While reading from google app engine

Tags: android, google-app-engine

```
 private class GetXMLTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
 {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls)
        {           
        String output = null;           
        try
        {   
            List<String> citations = new ArrayList<String>();
             for (String url : urls) 
                 {                  
                    output = getOutputFromUrl(url);   
                    citations.add(output);
                outputText.setText(output);
             }               
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Cant connect to server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return output;
    }           
  }
```

//I am trying to read a string from Google App Engine and set it to a textbox. The rest of the code is fine. but async task throws a fatal exception...Help!

Answer (score 3):

Delete this:

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Cant connect to server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Toast doesnt work in doInBackground()
And move

```
outputText.setText(output);
```

to

```
onPostExecute(){}
```

Comment: can he do instead `runOnUIThread(Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Cant connect to server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();'?

Comment: It could be possible. But wont the whole concept of AsyncTask collapse?

Comment: basically yes, but if this is just a small thing to do and there's a specific desired return value (like a String from a HTTP request) and the programer will want to notify the issues to the user, that's a way to do it

Comment: is there a better way that you wanna suggest?

Answer (score 0):

UI updates can't work in `doInBackground()` , using `runOnUi()` method you can do this..like this

```
runOnUIThread(Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Cant connect to server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```